# How to set automatic grid resize with difrent sizing of every grid

Tags: html, css

I dont know how to change CSS actual grid layout to auto resize sidebar/main/footer grid if content will be bigger then 1 frame. On example bellow is last sidebar under footer grid and if is sidebar grid bigger then 1 fr it will atomaticly hide footer grid.

As well if main grid have big amoung of text, it will hide again footer grid.. How to avoid that problem and probably auto resize grids on among of data on page?

```css
/* Page CSS */

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  background-color: #c9c9c9;
}


/* Layout */

.layout {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 5fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.1fr 0.1fr 1.2fr 0.3fr;
  grid-template-areas: "title title title title" "nav nav nav sidebar" "main main main sidebar" "footer footer footer footer";
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Title Box */

.title {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
  grid-area: title;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}


/* Menu Box */

nav {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
  grid-area: nav;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

nav li {
  padding: 13px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav li a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 0.3em;
  background-color: #000000;
  bottom: -0.9em;
  transition: all ease-in-out 350ms;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
}

nav li a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

nav li a:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}


/* Button style */

button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline: inherit;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 0.3em;
  bottom: -0.5em;
  background-color: #000000;
  transition: all ease-in-out 350ms;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
}

button:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Content Box */

main {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
  grid-area: main;
  padding: 10px;
}


/*
input[type="text"] {
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  input[type="text"]:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }

  .inputWithIcon input[type="text"] {
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  
  .inputWithIcon {
    position: relative;
  }

  .inputWithIcon i {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 8px;
    padding: 40px 10px;
    color: #aaa;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .inputWithIcon input[type="text"]:focus + i {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);

  }*/


/* Sidebar CSS */

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.box_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  float: right;
  display: grid;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  float: right;
}

.box_title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box_title i {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.box_content {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.box_content a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box_content table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.box_content i {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.box_content ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box_content li {
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box_content a:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 160, 0);
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.box_online {
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: rgb(5, 148, 0);
}

.box_offline {
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: rgb(148, 0, 0);
}


/* Profile Card */

.profiles-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.profile {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
  float: left;
  transition: all .3s ease
}

.profile:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.05);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
}

.profile a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.profile_image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
  display: block;
}

.profile_name {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.profile_info {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.profile_verifed {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: rgb(5, 148, 0);
}

.profile_unverifed {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: rgb(148, 0, 0);
}


/* Footer Box */

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
}


/* Error Messages */

.warn_info,
.warn_success,
.warn_warning,
.warn_error {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 12px;
}

.warn_info {
  color: #00529B;
  background-color: #BDE5F8;
}

.warn_success {
  color: #4F8A10;
  background-color: #DFF2BF;
}

.warn_warning {
  color: #9F6000;
  background-color: #FEEFB3;
}

.warn_error {
  color: #D8000C;
  background-color: #FFD2D2;
}


/* Responsive CSS */

@media only screen and (max-width:550px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 0.2fr 1fr 0.5fr 0.2fr;
    grid-template-areas: "title" "nav" "main" "sidebar" "footer";
  }
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="layout">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">Domů</a></li>
      <li><a href="switcher.php">Fun Switcher</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Radio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fotky</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Chat</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <main>

  </main>

  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="box_container">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box_title" id="close_sidebar"><i class='material-icons'>menu</i>Uživatelský panel</div>
        <div class="box_content">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Můj profil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Uživatelé</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nastavení</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Odhlásit se</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <div class="box_title"><i class='material-icons'>menu</i>Admin panel</div>
        <div class="box_content">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Správa uživatelů</a></li>
            <li><a href="../phpmyadmin">PhpMyAdmin</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="box">
        <div class="box_title"><i class='material-icons'>people</i>Online uživatelé</div>
        <div class="box_content">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td><i class="material-icons box_online">circle</i></td>
              <td><a href="">Admin</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><i class='material-icons box_offline'>circle</i></td>
              <td><a href="">Marek</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><i class='material-icons box_offline'>circle</i></td>
              <td><a href="">Mario Wiedermann</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><i class='material-icons box_offline'>circle</i></td>
              <td><a href="">Marek</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><i class='material-icons box_offline'>circle</i></td>
              <td><a href="">Mario Wiedermann</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><i class='material-icons box_offline'>circle</i></td>
              <td><a href="">Marek</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><i class='material-icons box_offline'>circle</i></td>
              <td><a href="">Mario Wiedermann</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><i class='material-icons box_offline'>circle</i></td>
              <td><a href="">Marek</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><i class='material-icons box_offline'>circle</i></td>
              <td><a href="">Mario Wiedermann</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><i class='material-icons box_offline'>circle</i></td>
              <td><a href="">Marek</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><i class='material-icons box_offline'>circle</i></td>
              <td><a href="">Mario Wiedermann</a></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>

  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: `min-height:100vh` instead `height:100vh` could be enough, unless you want the footer to show anytime ?

Comment: Yeah this set all grids visible, but if content(text) is long or somehow not fit to layout grids. It will destroy whole sizing design...

Comment: okay, what about no height set at all ? or why do you need 100vh ?

Comment: Well I dont need 100vh for all grid elemets. I need to fit all grids somehow "responsive" to look still same instead of content size in main/sidebar/footer grid. I can change the sizes of every grid.. But for example if I add plenty of text to main grid. Navbar and footer grid destroy styling and there is big gap on footer side.. Problem is I dont really know hot to set it "responsive" to content size.. Do you understand me? :D

Comment: min-height + a row template with 1fr for only main might do better, then, for the mediaquerie, use .layout not .container ;)  possible example https://jsfiddle.net/jpvsr7qz/ (gap instead margin, float is useless on grid or flex parent , ... ) have fun